# SQL Query Optimizer full exploration

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

According to [Connor Cunningham](https://www.sqlbits.com/Sessions/Event6/inside_the_sql_server_query_optimizer) and *Kimberly Tripp*

{Referenced from sql server 2008 r2 internalls book}.

There are 3 stages to plan exploration. Stage 0,1,2.
In **stage 0** the query is assigned a trival plan and in **stage 2**
 sql server does a full exploration of the plan.
How can I force sql server to do a full exploration of a given plan
 (stage 2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use trace flag 8757.

Have a looka at 
[More Undocumented Query Optimizer Trace Flags](http://www.benjaminnevarez.com/2012/04/more-undocumented-query-optimizer-trace-flags/) by Benjamin Nevarez.